# What happened to our question count?

Tags: discussion

There *were* approximately 12 024 questions about 18 hours ago; now there are 12 002. What happened?

[image: question count]

Comment: That's a lot of deleted questions, though.

Comment: @JasperLoy True enough.

Comment: I noticed that my rep dropped by about 200 and that my "answers" tally had gone down by one (happened to have that open in a tab before a refresh so noticed).  Presumably a question that I answered was deleted, but if that was the source then in was a pretty high-scoring answer so I'm confused.  I've found no way that I can find out which of my own answers (or questions, if I had any) have been deleted.

Comment: @JasperLoy, thanks.  I know that rep recalc exists but have no idea what triggers it.  This is the first unexplained change I've seen.  How do I contact a moderator to ask what happened?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Ping one in chat, perhaps?

Comment: Doubtless mods can delete questions straight off, but if three high-rep users *vote* to delete, that also does it. I only noticed a few days ago that I have this "superpower" - I may have been throwing my weight around, but there must be at least a couple of others doing the same.

Comment: ...also note that if *one* other person votes to deletes something, that's brought to my attention in my "Tools" screen. In most cases I've simply agreed with others voting to delete - it's not like I've spent ages mining the past for rubbishy questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm about to board a plane, so I can't really elaborate, but there have been a lot of flags in the past two days.

Comment: Well, enjoy your travels, and thank you for the insight.